# Angular animation not working (no transition between state)

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to implement a shadow background when a menu is opened.

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xve6ju

I don't understand what's missing, it should be working but there is no transition between the states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.

Firstly, `isMenuOpen` is supposed to have states of 'out' and 'in' but you've defined it as a boolean?

Secondly, you've specified your trigger `[@fadeInOutAnimation]` twice in your html.

You're also setting `isMenuOpen` to true with your Animate button, which will achieve nothing.

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5yx8n) amended working StackBlitz of your example.

Comment: thanks, didn't understand what was expected was not a on/off boolean but states strings.

Answer (score 1):

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOutAnimation', [
        state('out', style({
          opacity: 0
        })),
        state('in',  style({
          opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('out=>in', [
          animate('5s')
        ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  currentState = 'out';
  changeState() {
    this.currentState = this.currentState === 'in' ? 'out' : 'in';
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div 
*ngIf="isMenuOpen"
(click)="changeState()"
[@fadeInOutAnimation]="currentState"
class="shadow-background"
></div>

<button (click)="isMenuOpen = true">Animate</button>
```

stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzn3es

Comment: thanks for your time, I didn't understand what was expected was not a on/off boolean but state string.
Works like a charm ;)